# How to find best match of element within array to a set array node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, for-loop

Set array:

```
let arr = ["hello","my","name","connor"]
```

Array of all elements to compare to arr:

```
let allArr = ["hello my name is", "hello my name is connor", "hello connor name"]
```

So in this scenario, I would like a solution that picks the best element of `allArr` that matches to `arr`, its index with be suffice.

I have tried integrating two for loops e.g

```
for (i in allArr){
  for(x in arr){
     if(allArr[i].includes(arr[x]){
        do something
     }
  } 
}
```

But doesn't seem to work properly.
Need the fastest, but best explained solution[only applicable if it is complicated haha].

Comment: What defines the best element of `allArr` that matches to `arr`?

Comment: in this scenario, it would be index[1], as it includes the most of arr[x]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the count of each word in each sentences. Later, you could take the index of the max value.

```js
var words = ["hello", "my", "name", "connor"],
    sentences = ["hello my name is", "hello my name is connor", "hello connor name"],
    counts = sentences.map(s => words.reduce((sum, word) => sum + s.includes(word), 0)),
    indices = counts.reduce((r, c, i, a) => {
        if (!(a[r[0]] >= c)) {
            return [i];
        }
        if (a[r[0]] === c) {
            r.push(i);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(counts);
console.log(indices);
```

Comment: i think its simple as possible